# Single log is getting split into two events

Tags: splunk

I am not using props.conf. So I guess it is the default behavior.

Below is the single log:

```
2018-07-19 13:30:40.293 +0000  [http8080] INFO  RequestFilter- {
   "transaction_id" : "aaaaaaaaawwwwwwww",
   "http_method" : "POST",
   "date_time" : "2018-07-19 13:30:34.694 +0000",
   "requestId" : "20180719-dc7bc01d-b02c-43c8-932b-42af542ccefb"
 }
```

But it is coming in 2 events

```
2018-07-19 13:30:40.293 +0000  [http8080] INFO  RequestFilter- {
       "transaction_id" : "aaaaaaaaawwwwwwww",
       "http_method" : "POST",
```

And

```
"date_time" : "2018-07-19 13:30:34.694 +0000",
   "requestId" : "20180719-dc7bc01d-b02c-43c8-932b-42af542ccefb"
 }
```

It is always breaking from "date_time"

Any suggestions? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to adjust your [props.conf](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.1.2/Admin/Propsconf) to change the event break logic. By default, it will break whenever it detects a valid timestamp which suits most log formats.

This regex should match just the initial row:

```
LINE_BREAKER = \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}\s+\+\d{4}\s+\[.*\]
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
```

Comment: thanks Alec. I will try it. should I put props.conf in forwarder. Coz I don't find indexer folder.